# "System doesn't have any usb boot option" on corrupt dual boot

Tags: boot, usb, bios, uefi

A friend of mine is asking for help installing Ubuntu on their laptop. It used to have a Windows 10 (upgraded from 8) and Ubuntu 16 dual boot, but they ran `rm -rf /` in Ubuntu for laughs to wipe all their data. Next boot, it had to reinstall Win8, and so is now running that.

I tried to use a bootable USB key made with Rufus to install Ubuntu 20, but I'm getting the error message "System doesn't have any usb boot option" when attempting to boot from it. I updated the BIOS, no improvement. I've gone through [this tutorial](https://appuals.com/fix-system-doesnt-have-any-usb-boot-option/) which has some solutions but none of them work. The PC doesn't have a working CD drive any more, so I'm a bit stumped. Are there any solutions I can still try?

Comment: *The bootable USB drive wasn’t made correctly* this is likely the problem. With Rufus you need to explicitly select UEFI/GPT before burning.

Comment: @ChanganAuto you mean in the target system field? the only option is "UEFI or BIOS", so I assume that covers that

Comment: No, it doesn't. That is the option for BIOS/Legacy, the option you don't want if Windows was properly installed in UEFI mode. Again, UEFI (only UEFI) and GPT.

Comment: @ChanganAuto tried it with UEFI and GPT, no difference.

Comment: Try a different USB after assuring the ISO you downloaded is fine.

Comment: @ChanganAuto New USB key + using UEFI & GPT worked, thank you! If you type it out into an answer I'll accept it so you get max points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The bootable USB drive wasn’t made correctly

this is likely the problem. With Rufus you need to explicitly select **UEFI/GPT** before burning.

Also assure the downloaded ISO isn't corrupt.
Use a different USB key just in case.

Comment: _"With Rufus you need to explicitly select UEFI/GPT before burning"_. No, that is incorrect. The defaults of Rufus create a dual BIOS+UEFI bootable drive when using a Ubuntu ISO, thereby preserving the dual BIOS+UEFI boot feature of the source ISO. So, unless OP got in error in Rufus when creating the drive, or altered the options from the default, their drive was most likely created correctly. Especially, they certainly don't need to explicitly select GPT or UEFI. Source: I am the main developer of Rufus.

Comment: @Akeo The thing is with MBR/BIOS+UEFI (something that probably should read as BIOS + UEFI (Legacy)) it isn't even recognized in systems without CSM support or set to UEFI only. If it preserved the "dual BIOS+UEFI boot feature of the source ISO" it would be indistinguishable from the "dd" mode everything else uses. Furthermore I've read your (Rufus) blog post with the reasoning behind the selective bootloader selection and didn't found it particularly compelling, an attempt to solve a non-issue (personal opinion). That such decision has created far more problems that it solved is a fact though

Comment: _"something that probably should read as BIOS + UEFI (Legacy)"_ No, it really is BIOS/UEFI-CSM __AND__ pure UEFI from the same device, just like the original ISO. _"If it preserved the "dual BIOS+UEFI boot feature of the source ISO"_ It does. Unless Ubuntu changed something on their ISO very recently, I have tested the pure UEFI and legacy/BIOS boot from the default media created by Rufus often enough to assert that Rufus with the default options __does__ preserve the dual BIOS + UEFI feature of the source ISO. The difference with DD mode has nothing to do with that feature.

Comment: Be also mindful that the FAQ entry I believe you are referring to (coz I've only ever posted one blog entry about Rufus features) applies to Windows and Windows only, where, and this is especially true with the advent of Windows 11, users may really want to make sure they install the OS in UEFI mode and not inadvertently in BIOS/Legacy mode. But this does not apply to Linux, and especially not Ubuntu (though you can force UEFI-only if you change the default options).